# How to get scroll spy to work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I cant get my scroll spy to work, and I have tried everything, what am I doing wrong?  I have looked at countless examples and I seem to have everything correct. Here is the whole file, Im thinking there are maybe some conflicting css?

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TCS Event Rentals</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      body {
       position: relative;

      }

      .jumbotron img {
        width: 100%;
       height: auto;

      }

      .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 85px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        height: 550px;
        background-image: 
url(https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1447/98829743/stock-photo-wedding-tent-set-up-for-an-outdoor-wedding-or-other-event-chairs-set-up-for-an-outdoor-ceremony-98829743.jpg);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
      }

      .jumbotron h2 {
        color: white;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }

       .navbar-fixed-top {
      min-height: 125px;
      }

      .navbar-header {
        height: 125px;
      }

      a.navbar-brand {
        height: 125px;
      }

      a.navbar-brand > img {
        margin-top: -13px;
      }

      ul.nav {
        margin-top: 60px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-nav > li > a {
        line-height: 20px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }

      div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      .navbar-toggle {
        margin-top: 30px;
      }

      ul.nav {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }


    </style>



</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <!-- <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Contact Us</a> -->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eventrental">Event Rental Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#eventserved">Events Served</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav><!-- End Navbar -->

    <!-- Jumbotron -->

    <div class="Jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <!--<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQNHBdJdFb6Chukad-YBtL4RXRY0uyR_TI5-hvVYuIHZjQwZB-j" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"> -->

            <h2>Serving the Special Events Industry</h2>

            <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#gallery"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">View Our Gallery</a>
            </div>

        </div><!-- End Container -->
    </div><!-- End Jumbotron -->

    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="aboutus">
                <h2>About Us<small> Check out the feedback</small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <blockquote>
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                      <footer>John Doe</footer>
                  </blockquote>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <blockquote>
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                      <footer>John Doe</footer>
                  </blockquote>
                </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <blockquote>
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                      <footer>John Doe</footer>
                  </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div><!--End Row -->
        </section>
    </div> <!-- End Container -->

    <!--call to action -->
    <section>
        <div class="well">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h3>Contact Us to plan your next event</h3>
                <p>Enter your name and email</p>

                <form action="" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label form="subscription">Contact Us</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label form="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                    <hr>
                </form>
            </div><!--end container -->
        </div><!-- end well -->
    </section><!-- end Call to action -->


    <!-- Gallery -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="gallery">
                <h2>Gallery<small> Check out our Gallery</small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="https://partytimerental.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/100-x-380-Century-Tent-Denver-View-3.x30701.jpg" alt="text of image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="https://partytimerental.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/100-Wide-Century-Tent-Rocky-Mountains-CO-View-5.x30701.jpg" alt="text of image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="https://partytimerental.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/100-x-380-Century-Tent-Denver-View-3.x30701.jpg" alt="text of image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="https://partytimerental.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/100-x-380-Century-Tent-Denver-View-3.x30701.jpg" alt="text of image">
                    </div>

                </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- end carousel -->

        </section>
    </div>

    <!-- Event Rental Products -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="eventrental">
                <h2>Event Rental Products<small>Browse our selection of rental products</small></h2>
            </div><!-- End Page Header -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img src="img/imac.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/homestratosphere/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/5Way-AccentChairs100.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img src="http://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/16513837?wid=360&hei=360&qlt=80&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Row -->

            <hr>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            <h4>This is the heading</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
                            <h4>This is the heading</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>
                            <h4>This is the heading</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Row -->

        </section>
    </div><!-- End Container -->

    <!-- Events Served -->

    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="eventserved">
                <h2>Events Served<small>Past events we served</small></h2>
            </div><!-- End Page Header -->
        </section>
    </div><!-- End Container -->

    <!-- Contact -->

    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="contact">
                <h2>Contact Us<small>Contact us for more</small></h2>
            </div><!-- End Page Header -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p>Send us a message, or contact us from the address below</p>

                    <address>
                        <strong>TCS Event Rentals</strong></br>
                        Lear Dr</br>
                        Burlington, NC 27310</br>
                        P: 1-800-888-8888
                    </address>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter your Email Address">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Your Website</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-url" placeholder="If you have any">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Any Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End Form Group -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Row -->

        </section>
    </div><!-- End Container -->

    <!-- Footer -->

        <footer>
          <hr>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h3>Contact Us to plan your next event</h3>
                <p>Enter your name and email</p>

                <form action="" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label form="subscription">Contact Us</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label form="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                </form>

                <hr>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/slmwebdesignco">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/slmwebdesignco">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/slmwebdesignco">Youtube</a></li>
                </ul>

                <p>&copy;Copyright 2017</p>
            </div><!--end container -->

        </footer>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires relative positioning: The element with data-spy="scroll" requires the CSS position property, with a value of "relative" to work properly.

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

It's working just add content for corresponding hashes, and resize the window height in order to see it.

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1">

        <!-- <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Contact Us</a> -->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#eventrental">Event Rental Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#eventserved">Events Served</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!-- End Navbar -->




<div id="aboutus" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="eventrental" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="eventserved" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I actually have the css for the body's position to relative. I will post all the code here, maybe its some other css that is affecting it? The contact on the nav stays highlighted regardless, I am not sure what could cause that...

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the solution through more research, I simply had to add css: height: 100%; to the body element. Everything works perfectly now.